# D3.js tree node name getting scattered

Tags: d3.js, microsoft-edge

I have created tree using D3.js. While dragging node in d3.js tree, node names getting scattered on Microsoft edge browser of windows 10. Dragging is working fine in all browsers except Microsoft edge browser of windows 10.any help on this?